# Robot.txt says is blocked but not blocking anything?

Tags: wordpress, adsense, robots.txt, google-search-console

So I am trying to get Ads on my site. Its been reviewing for awhile so I am doing some digging on maybe something is blocking the bots from crawling. I found this out today, tell me if it means anything.

First: I fetched and rendered my site on google search console.
[image]

I clicked the robots.txt link on the right of the above image and it showed this:
[image]

So then: I did a robot crawl as all google bots and got allowed on my robots file.
Live file:[image]

In my file manager of my website the above picture is of my actual robots.txt file. So are my ads not able to be verified due to my robots file blocking the 2nd stage of verification?

Answer (score 0):

Your robots.txt can only block URLs from your host.

The message from Google Search Console is about an external URL. That external host’s robots.txt blocks crawling of the URL in question.

There’s nothing you could do about it (except for hosting the external script yourself, but that’s of course not possible in all cases).